# want to display arrays of data in table using template file in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, template-toolkit, multiple-columns

I have different arrays of data stored from my SQL :

```
push( @bugid,$bug_id);
push(@assign,$assignd_to);
push(@stat,$stats);
push(@res,$resol);
push(@rat,$rate);
push(@sev,$prior);
push(@op,$o_p);
push(@shrt,$shor_desc);

 $vars->{'bugid'}= \@bugid;
 $vars->{'Ticket'}= $ticket_no;
 $vars->{'Assigne'}= \@assign;
 $vars->{'stats'}= \@stat;
 $vars->{'resoltion'}= \@res;
 $vars->{'rate'}= \@rat;
 $vars->{'priorty'}= \@sev;
 $vars->{'opsys'}= \@op;
 $vars->{'shrtdesc'}= \@shrt;
```

And i have passed this to a template file for displaying purpose like below :

```
$template->process('reports/gayathri_old-ticketlist.html.tmpl', $vars)
     || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
```

And i want to display the details in a table .
ie, corresponding to each *bugid*, i want to display all other fields.

I have added the code like this in template file.i got the table format.but the values are entering into each column in a wrong manner.

```
<table border='1' bgcolor='#eefff3'>

<tr><td><b>BUG ID</b></td>
<td><b>TICKET NO</b></td>
<td><b>ASSIGNED TO</b></td>
<td><b>BUG STATUS</b></td>
<td><b>RESOLUTION</b></td>
<td><b>RATING</b></td>
<td><b>PRIORITY</b></td>
<td><b>OP-SYS</b></td>
<td><b>SHORT DESCRIPTION</b></td></tr>
[% FOREACH Assigne  = Assigne %]
[% FOREACH stats = stats %]
[% FOREACH resoltion = resoltion %]
[% FOREACH rate = rate %]
[% FOREACH priorty = priorty %]
[% FOREACH opsys = opsys  %]
[% FOREACH shrtdesc = shrtdesc %]
[% FOREACH bugid  = bugid %]

<tr>
  <td>
      &nbsp; <A HREF="show_bug.cgi?id=[% bugid %]"> [% bugid %] </A><br>
  </td>

  <td>
     &nbsp;  [% Ticket %]
 </td>

 <td>
     &nbsp;  [% Assigne %]
 </td>

  <td>
     &nbsp;  [% stats %]
  </td>
  <td>

    &nbsp;  [% resoltion %]

  </td>
   <td>

    &nbsp;  [% rate %]

   </td>
   <td>

    &nbsp;  [% priorty %]

   </td>
   <td>

    &nbsp;  [% opsys %]

   </td>
    <td>

     &nbsp;  [% shrtdesc %]

    </td>
</tr>
  [% END %]
 [% END %]
   [% END %]
   [% END %]
  [% END %]
   [% END %]
   [% END %]
    [% END %]
   </table>
```

could any one please correct this?

Comment: could any one please reply this, as this is very urgent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @items;
while(my($bug_id,$icket_no,$assignd_to,$stats,$resol,$rate,$prior,$o_p,$shor_desc)
=$sth->fetchrow_array()) {
my $item = {
bugid => $bug_id,
ticket => $icket_no,
assign_to => $assignd_to,
status => $stats,
resolution => $resol,
priority => $prior,
opsys => $o_p,
shortdesc => $shor_desc,
};
push(@items, $item);
}
$vars-> {items} = \@items;
```

Then passed to template file,

```
$template->process('reports/gayathri_old-ticketlist.html.tmpl', $vars)
 || ThrowTemplateError($template->error());
```

Then in the template file :

```
<b>Bugs Corresponding to ticket no :[% item.ticket %]</b><br>
<br>

<table border='1' bgcolor='#eefff3'>

  <tr><td><b>BUG ID</b></td>
 <td><b>TICKET NO</b></td>
  <td><b>ASSIGNED TO</b></td>
  <td><b>BUG STATUS</b></td>
 <td><b>RESOLUTION</b></td>
 <td><b>RATING</b></td>
 <td><b>PRIORITY</b></td>
 <td><b>OP-SYS</b></td>
 <td><b>SHORT DESCRIPTION</b></td></tr>

 [%- FOREACH item in items -%]
 <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="show_bug.cgi?id=[% item.bugid %]"> [%  item.bugid %] </a><br>
        &nbsp; [% item.ticket %]<br/>
         &nbsp; [% item.assign_to %] <br/>
         &nbsp; [% item.status %] <br/>
         &nbsp; [% item.resolution %] <br/>
         &nbsp; [% item.priority %] <br/>
        &nbsp; [% item.opsys %] <br/>
        &nbsp; [% item.shortdesc %] <br/>

      </td>
  </tr>
   [%- END -%]

</table>

 [% PROCESS global/footer.html.tmpl %]
```

But is is providing a blank page

Comment: Why are you referring to `item.ticket` outside the `FOREACH item in items` loop? `item` has no scope there. I would add a display of `[% items.size %]` before the loop to confirm that `$vars->{items}` is > 0 and does indeed contain a collection that the loop can iterate over.

Answer (score 4):

All those nested `FOREACH` statements are going to create loops within loops. I'd say that's why you're not getting the output you want. I'm not sure what the impact of redefining the variables (`FOREACH bugid = bugid` etc) will be.

The data design is horrible, but you could work with it, doing something like:

```
[%- SET i = 0;
    WHILE i < bugid.size; -%]
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="show_bug.cgi?id=[% bugid.$i %]"> [% bugid.$i %] </a><br>
        &nbsp; [% Assigne.$i %]<br/>
         ...etc
    </td>
</tr>
[%-     SET i = i + 1;
    END -%]
```

... effectively iterating through all the elements of **one** of those arrays, and using the ordinal position for **all** of them. `bugid.$i` resolves to `bugid.0` for the first element in the array.

But I wouldn't do that.

I would generate the original data as an array of hashrefs, and then iterate through them.

== Perl ==

```
my @items;

# in some loop
my $item = {
    bugid => $bugid,
    assign_to => $assign_to,
    status => $stat,
    ..etc
};
push @items, $item;
# end of loop

$vars->{items} = \@items;
```

== Template ==

```
[%- FOREACH item in items -%]
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="show_bug.cgi?id=[% item.bugid %]"> [% item.bugid %] </a><br>
            &nbsp; [% item.assign_to %]<br/>
             ...etc
        </td>
    </tr>
[%- END -%]
```

Hope that's helpful. And for pity's sake, decide on a naming convention for your variables and stick to it. As a fellow programmer once put it to me: "A standard that sucks is better than a constantly changing one." :-)